# how to declare a php class with a variable name

Tags: php

is there a way in php
to declare a class using a variable
ie (this doesnt work - but its here to give you an idea of my intention):

```
$myname = "the_class";
class $myname {
 ...
}
```

i also tried:

```
define("MYNAME","the_class");
class MYNAME{
 ...
}
```

and i tried:

```
$myname = "the_class";
class $$myname {
 ...
}
```

this doesnt really help:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

nor does this:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/keyword.class.php

thanks very much for your help

Comment: Why on Earth would you want to do that?

Comment: perhaps if you told us what you plan to do with it, we may find a better way to accomplish your end goal.  I can't imagine a reason why this would be needed...

Comment: I would appear that your are defining $myname as a String, Not a class. Can one variable point to two objects?  This is like a (math) function 1x -> 2ys

Comment: +1: I'm getting tired of these rabid downvoters who can't even bother to explain themselves. The question is valid. If you disagree with that the question asker is trying to do... simply answer the question then provide an alternative. As for why you would want to do such a thing... well, it has its uses.

Comment: Agree with @Fake Code Monkey Rashid. One *valid* case I can infer from his logic is if hes is trying to mock or stub something. Maybe he's working on a test suite? His question was clear and straightforward and even "showed his work" with research notes.. doesn't warrant downvote imho.

Comment: Alternative answer is in duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12230252/creating-a-class-name-from-a-variable/12230281#12230281

Answer (score 7):

Sure, use php to write to a file with the name you want, then require that file. You could also use [`eval`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php), e.g. something like: `eval("class $myname { ... };");`

For more complicated cases, use a library such as Zend's [`CodeGenerator`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.codegenerator.html) (example [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.codegenerator.examples.html)).

Answer (score 0):

Please don't up/downvote this response or mark it as the answer.

[Eugen Rieck's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7438324/how-to-declare-a-php-class-with-a-variable-name#comment16389230_7438324) is the best one, but got buried in the comments.

[The answer he linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12230252/creating-a-class-name-from-a-variable/12230281#12230281) shows how to use class_alias() to name a class to a define.  This is useful if you are writing a library class and wish to let the user name it whatever they want, for example by setting a define in a config file.

So if you are writing a library containing MyLibraryClass, you could let the user name it to something like LC for conciseness so they can write LC::someFunction() or LC->someFunction instead of having to write the whole thing out.