# Creating a class name from a variable

Tags: php, codeigniter, variables, model

I would like to define the class name using variables in PHP. Is this possible?

Let me explain.

I am a small custom CMS that allows the end user to configure a prefix for the table names. So a user can define the prefix such as "rc_". The problem is, I have a lot of models that use the table name as the class. So for example, if one of my tables is `rc_posts`, the model will be called

```
class MyModel_Rc_posts extends MyModelController {
         // code here
}
```

Is there any way to define a class using variables in PHP WITHOUT using `eval()` such as:

```
class MyModel_{$PREFIX}posts extends MyModelController {
// code here
}
```

The reason I want to avoid eval, is because some of these classes can get pretty long. Suggestions appreciated.

Comment: exact duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7438324/how-to-declare-a-php-class-with-a-variable-name

Comment: Code smell detected: Why would you need to tie the domain object name to the table name if both are completely different: One is storage, the other is domain model. =\ If you really want this, you should have `Table Data Gateway` with a property representing the table name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [class_alias](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.class-alias.php) - it should help you make this even readable!

Just to make this clear: You create your class with a "normal" name, then add an alias name on demand. The alias name can be any string, this includes a string stored in a variable.

**Edit**

While I think, that `class_alias()` is the way to go, here is an example on how to do it without it.

From your OQ:

```
class MyModel_Rc_posts extends MyModelController {
         // code here
}
```

Now

```
eval("class MyModel_{$PREFIX}posts extends MyModel_Rc_posts {};");
```

should do something very similar to `class_alias()`.

Going this rout could be necessary, if you need `get_class()` later - on an aliased class, it will give you the original (static) classname, not the alias. With the ugly `eval()`/`extends` trick you get the dynamic name.

Comment: Awesome. I will give this a shot and reply back!